# Multicall function in Ethernaut Challenge #24: PuzzleWallet

Tags: solidity

I'm following the tutorial here: https://blog.dixitaditya.com/ethernaut-level-24-puzzle-wallet

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "../helpers/UpgradeableProxy-08.sol";

contract PuzzleProxy is UpgradeableProxy {
    address public pendingAdmin;
    address public admin;

    constructor(address _admin, address _implementation, bytes memory _initData) UpgradeableProxy(_implementation, _initData) {
        admin = _admin;
    }

    modifier onlyAdmin {
      require(msg.sender == admin, "Caller is not the admin");
      _;
    }

    function proposeNewAdmin(address _newAdmin) external {
        pendingAdmin = _newAdmin;
    }

    function approveNewAdmin(address _expectedAdmin) external onlyAdmin {
        require(pendingAdmin == _expectedAdmin, "Expected new admin by the current admin is not the pending admin");
        admin = pendingAdmin;
    }

    function upgradeTo(address _newImplementation) external onlyAdmin {
        _upgradeTo(_newImplementation);
    }
}

contract PuzzleWallet {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public maxBalance;
    mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function init(uint256 _maxBalance) public {
        require(maxBalance == 0, "Already initialized");
        maxBalance = _maxBalance;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyWhitelisted {
        require(whitelisted[msg.sender], "Not whitelisted");
        _;
    }

    function setMaxBalance(uint256 _maxBalance) external onlyWhitelisted {
      require(address(this).balance == 0, "Contract balance is not 0");
      maxBalance = _maxBalance;
    }

    function addToWhitelist(address addr) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the owner");
        whitelisted[addr] = true;
    }

    function deposit() external payable onlyWhitelisted {
      require(address(this).balance <= maxBalance, "Max balance reached");
      balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function execute(address to, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external payable onlyWhitelisted {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        (bool success, ) = to.call{ value: value }(data);
        require(success, "Execution failed");
    }

    function multicall(bytes[] calldata data) external payable onlyWhitelisted {
        bool depositCalled = false;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            bytes memory _data = data[i];
            bytes4 selector;
            assembly {
                selector := mload(add(_data, 32))
            }
            if (selector == this.deposit.selector) {
                require(!depositCalled, "Deposit can only be called once");
                // Protect against reusing msg.value
                depositCalled = true;
            }
            (bool success, ) = address(this).delegatecall(data[i]);
            require(success, "Error while delegating call");
        }
    }
}
```

The following questions pertain to the function `multicall()`:

- Why does it take `bytes[] calldata data` as the parameter?
- What does this function do line by line?

Answer (score 1):

The multicall() function allows you to execute multiple function calls in a single transaction. It takes an array of byte arrays as an argument, where each element in the array represents the encoded data for a function call. The function processes each element in the array by extracting the function selector and calling the corresponding function using the delegatecall() function. If any of the function calls fail, the transaction is rolled back and an exception is thrown. Additionally, the function includes a check to ensure that the deposit() function is only called once in the batch.

Comment: Why does it take bytes[] calldata data as the parameter?

Comment: multicall() function takes calldata data as an array of encoded ABI representation of contract functions. The function then calls all of them in a single transaction using delegatecall.